# Trouble understanding math in expectation value definition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, eigenvalue

This is the part of the equation I do understand:
$$
\langle A \rangle_\alpha = \langle \alpha | A | \alpha \rangle = \sum_{a}\sum_{b} \langle \alpha | b\rangle \langle b | A | a\rangle \langle a | \alpha \rangle =\\
$$
Between these lines is the logic I do not understand and need help with. It is not described in the book.
$$
=\sum_a a |\langle a | \alpha \rangle |^2
$$

It feels like the dual space and space pairing for finite dimensional spaces (kroenecker delta) is used somehow since only one of the summation variables are left. But when I tried to do the math I ended up with a sum of vectors, not a scalar. So I need help! Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: they're using the fact that $| a \rangle$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $a$ (I know, confusing notation).  Try to use that fact to "take $A$ out" from in between $\langle b |$ and $| a \rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are leraning your quantum physics from J.J.Sakurai? I remember that part and if you try reading carefuly previous segment you ll see the solution. But in case you are not, here it is.Matrix A written in basis of eigenstates of A is diagonal. So, double summation went into the square of projection of given state alpha on to the eigenstates. Because matrix is diagonal, different id est mixed coefficients vanish.Also because action of A operator on eigenstate can be written as a number (called eigenvalue) times its eigenstate operator A is written just as the value of A on the state a.
Hope this clears up some things.

[image]

Comment: I am refreshing my quantum physics. I didn't think of letting the operator have eigenvalues which stopped me from understanding. The  whole matrix thing feels too obfuscated, since I am reading in my freetime for fun I don't really need to learn  how to write the thing as a matrix :-)

Comment: But it is Sakurai? :-)